# how to make query retention cohort ini sql?

Tags: sql

Create monthly retention cohorts (the groups, or cohorts, can be defined based upon the date that a user completely purchased a product) and then how many of them (%) coming back for the following months in 2022. After analyzing the retention cohort, is there any interesting insight that we can get?

Notes: initial start date can be defined using first purchase from each user in table order
Expected output:

- Month
- M (# of users in current month)
- M1 (# of users in following months)
- M2 (# of users in following two months)
- M3 (# of users in following three months)
- M4 (# of users in following four months)
- M5 (# of users in following five months)
- M6 (# of users in following six months)

[picure of table dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqKkN.png)

Link to dataset https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bigquery-public-data/thelook-ecommerce?q=search&referrer=search&project=sincere-torch-350709

pleasee could you help me for this, im so new bie on sql, thanks for a help.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Post the code what you have tried with sample data

Comment: Welcome. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a searchable archive of questions and answers for everybody to use. When the most important parts of your question are in images and links, you make it much harder to search. That means your question, and any possible answers, won't benefit anybody but you. That, in turn, means you probably won't get answers. Please [edit] your question to include your information in the text of the question.